# Kivy installation command not found

Tags: python, windows, cmd, kivy

I wanted to install kivy on Windows 10 and the first thing it said was that I should type python --version on cmd. So, I did it and it only said command 'python' not found/ written wrong or something like that(but in German because I'm German). Does anyone know how to fix that? I already tried to install kivy for like 3 hours.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
That kind of installing python modules only works when the package is suitable with the version of python you are using. And if it is saying python not found you may have to set a path in cmd to where your python is located. First type python and if no error pops out that means it is now recognized. Now set a path to the script pip.py that is used for installing python modules. you can set it as e.g
set path='%PATH%';c:\type the python path\scripts
once that is done then
 type pip install kivy
hope that works for you.
```